# Change Iframe SRC & Scroll to top using Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, scroll

Hope you are all well.

I am trying to create my own video gallery using html, CSS, and Javascript.
My idea is that there are thumbnails that are hyperlinks that when clicked, scroll to the top and plays a youtube video in an iframe.

So far i have managed to get both the scroll to top and changing the iframe source to work individually. But, annoyingly, they do not seem to work when they are together.

Could anybody give me tips on the best way of achieving my goal?

Here is the jsfiddle of the 'changing iframe source' code working: jsfiddle.net/2SH97/ (This has the design of the page and what it'll look like at the end) 
Here is the jsfiddle of the 'scroll to top' code: jsfiddle.net/RpPEe/229/ (a short version of the scroll to top with my attempt to change iframe source)

Thanks in advance.

Best,

Comment: You should provide code of your attempts with a jsfiddle if you can.

Comment: Here is a link to my code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/2vSt9/

Answer (score 0):

```
 function scrollt(){
     $("body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 600);
  }

 $("[target='projectsiframe']").on('click',function () {
  $("#ifr").attr('src',$(this).attr('href'));
  scrollt();
 });
 DEMO
 http://jsfiddle.net/2SH97/3/
```

Comment: This works great, i couldn't be happier.
Love & Light to you my dear friend x